# Does it make sense to have a pressure and flow controller on a single closed line?

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control, valves

I have seen P&IDs in which a single line has both a pressure and flow control valve. Based on my understanding of Bernoulli's equation however this doesn't make sense to me - because ultimately flow velocity and pressure are dependent on one another, by controlling one you are affecting the other (due to conservation of energy).

See for instance the image below:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how this could work in practise?

Best wishes and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to NMech's answer, the pressure regulator sets the maximum pressure that the system will see while the flow control limits the maximum flow that the downstream system will receive. This may be important in filling or pressurising the system and may also limit the flow rate in the event of a burst or severe leak.

Comment: OP could confirm this by finding additional information on the valves in question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does. If you don't have them in parallel then what you will have is a single pressure "mapped" to a single flow (or sort of). That can be a bit limitting.

E.g. imagine a chemical process that requires a gas at a certain pressure to complete. If that the gas is consumed in the process, and you decided to increase the output flow you'd need to increase the flow of the gas.

In that case having only a pressure regulator will not work.

Also using only a flow regulator might give you higher pressure than desired.

So bottom line is, that you need both flow and pressure regulator, if you need to control both pressure and flow *independently*.